# `write': "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError) while writing to file from url

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, open-uri

I am getting error:

```
write': "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

from line:

```
open(uri) {|url_file| tempfile.write(url_file.read)}
```

relevant code is:

```
require 'tempfile'
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'
..
uri = URI.parse(@download_link)
tempfile = Tempfile.create(file_name)
open(uri) {|url_file| tempfile.write(url_file.read)}`
..
```

It runs completely fine if I run it like `ruby lib/file.rb`, but gives error when I run it in rails environment: `rails runner lib/file.rb`.

Most questions with this error refer to gem installation scenarios. My guess that I have to include/update some gems, but have no idea which.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `force_encoding`:

```
open(uri) {|url_file| tempfile.write(url_file.read.force_encoding("UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 16):

Accepted answer is fine, but I think it is worth mentioning that You can also set encoding when creating/opening Tempfile, for example:

```
Tempfile.new("file.pdf", encoding: 'ascii-8bit') # or 'utf-8'
```

Answer (score 16):

This should solve the problem.

```
data = URI.parse(@download_link).read
tempfile = Tempfile.create(file_name)
tempfile.binmode # This will help deal encoding problem with download files from the internet
tempfile.write(data)
```

binmode is binary mode

Comment: This is the answer that addresses the real core of the issue

Comment: This answer did it for me